# Sharing on friends' timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-sharer

How can i enable sharing items on friends timeline like in picture. I am using Facebook sharer url like on [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/86EvD/) which is on code below. Which parameter am i have to add this url to share on friends' timeline?

```
<a target="_blank" title="Share on Facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?%20app_id=<?php echo FACEBOOK_APP_ID;?>&%20link=<?php echo urlencode(url_cevir(APP_BASE_URL.'/index.php?view=s&artist='.$a[artistname].'&track='.$a[trackname]));?>&%20picture=<?php echo $a[pic_large];?>&%20name=<?php echo urlencode($a[artistname].' - '.$a[trackname]);?>&caption=cruisear.com&description=Discover new artists, listen new songs.&redirect_uri=<?php echo APP_BASE_URL; ?>"> <img src="img/face.gif" alt="share on facebook" /> </a>
```

[image]

Comment: I can't test it right now, but i'm pretty sure that item is shared on friend's timeline by default (as in, it appears on timeline anyway)

Comment: No. I have added a demo fiddle on original post and below this comment. As you see on fiddle, default settings alow you to sent only to your timeline. http://jsfiddle.net/86EvD/

Answer (score 2):

In order to share something on friend's wall you need to add  `to` parameter to your link:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
app_id=458358780877780&
  link=<?php echo $link ?>/&
  picture=<?php echo $pic ?>&
  to=<?php echo $friendId ?>
  name=<?php echo $name ?>&
  caption=<?php echo $caption ?>&
  description=<?php echo $description ?>&
  redirect_uri=<?php echo $url ?>
```

Comment: This is nice but isn't there any practical way of setting section in red box on picture?

Comment: none that i know of. The picture might be outdated. In the [feed dialog documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) the image doesn't have the field you have in red box

Comment: @Darvex, Any idea on how to send to multiple people by setting to:<list>

Comment: As far as i remember, in the "to" field, you can just enter IDs of people (comma separated), and the message will be sent to them. But i suggest you check that @RaxitSheth

Comment: @Darvex it is not allowing more than one Id/Username in "to" field.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for Facebook's new Send button.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/

Comment: My experiments with the send button indicate it sends the object to someone's FB Messages, not to their timeline.